# Repeatedly check conditions inside loop or check up front but have two loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have implemented a python function in 2 different ways, as shown below:

1st:

```
def  foo(varA, varB):
    if not (varA or varB):
        return False

    for test1 in test2:
        if varA:
            # Perform Action A
        if varB:
            # Perform Action B

    return True
```

2nd:

```
def foo(varA, varB):
    if not (varA or varB):
        return False

    if varA:
        for test1 in test2:
            # Perform Action A

    if varB:
        for test1 in test2:
            # Perform Action B

    return True
```

I want to know which method will take less time in execution.

Comment: You should time your functions: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html

Comment: Side note: `is False` is *not* how you should test for boolean truth. Use `if not varA and not varB:` instead. Or `if not (varA or varB):`. I've edited the code so as to not distract from the main point of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It depends**.

There is no definitive answer here. It depends on the cost of iteration, the number of elements you are iterating over, and on the cost of testing for boolean truth. If `bool(varA)` or `bool(varB)` is *costly* (has a slow implementation) then you'd want to avoid that cost and just loop over `test2` twice.

But if iteration over `test2` is slow (`it = iter(test2)` then repeated calls to `next(it)` are slow), then you'd want to avoid iterating twice.

In the end, you have two O(N) linear algorithms here. Which one is faster depends entirely on the fixed costs. You'll have to *time* your code to know which one to pick. Make sure to run the tests *many times* with different scenarios, because it matters what the normal distributions between `bool(varA)` and  `bool(varB)` are, how often is either going to be true? If one or the other is *rarely* true, that can make a difference in overall execution costs.

If we assume that `varA` and `varB` are the same type of object and there is no difference in cost to test for their boolean truth, then cast as a formula, the two options costs can be expressed as:

```
cost_iteration * length * (2 * cost_test)
```

and

```
(2 * cost_test) + ((1 + probability_of_both_true) * cost_iteration * length)
```

where `cost_iteration` is the cost to advance the `test2` iterator by one step, `length` the number of times you need to iterate, and `cost_test` the cost of determining the boolean truth of `varA` or `varB`.

Note that I'm ignoring the possibility that `test2` is not an iterable, but a single-use iterator. If `test2` is an iterator, then you can't loop over it more than once and so you don't have a choice.

As you can see from the above formulas, even using *standard Python types*, with no custom [`__bool__` or `__len__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) for `varA` and `varB`, and no custom [`__iter__` or `__getitem__` implementation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) for `test2`, and where `test2` is not an open file object (I/O is *slow*), it *still* depends on how often *both* values are true.

This is easily visible using some simple time trial tests with the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html), and with `test2 = range(100)`:

```py
>>> import timeit
>>> def option1(a, b):
...     if not (a or b): return False
...     for _ in test2:
...         if a: pass
...         if b: pass
...
>>> def option2(a, b):
...     if not (a or b): return False
...     if a:
...         for _ in test2: pass
...     if b:
...         for _ in test2: pass
...
>>> test2 = range(100)
```

with *both* variables true:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("t(True, True)", "from __main__ import option1 as t")
1.917803047000234
>>> timeit.timeit("t(True, True)", "from __main__ import option2 as t")
2.0743740369998704
```

with only *one* variable true:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("t(True, False)", "from __main__ import option1 as t")
1.7149272380002003
>>> timeit.timeit("t(True, False)", "from __main__ import option2 as t")
1.095426841000517
```

`timeit.timeit()` by default re-runs the test 1 million times, so the above times are in *microseconds per execution*.

If both `varA` and `varB` are *predominantly* true, then the first option is ever so slightly faster. But if it is more common for only *one* of these to be true, then you'd want the second option, as it doesn't have to test so often, so wins out by a significant margin.

The timings can differ if there are more elements in `test2` to iterate over, so which one you select also has to take into account what your typical iteration count is going to be.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. By using timeit, i found that in all cases, except A and B both True, second method is slightly fast.

Answer (score -1):

If neither varA nor varB are false, the second solution is likely slower, as you're looping over `test2` twice.

Comment: The first may be faster but I wouldn't say "definitely". It depends which is slower, an extra loop or extra `if` checks. Could you back your answer up empirically?

Comment: 'definitely'? They are both O(n) algorithms, with one of them having a slightly higher cost by iterating twice, the other with a slightly higher cost for testing each iteration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Updated to _likely_ instead of _definitely_.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'll admit I don't have hard data.  My reasoning is that if `test2` is large then the second solution is obviously faster; and if `test2` is short, then the second solution is still faster because the overhead for another full loop iteration has to be higher than the overhead for a few boolean comparisons (doesn't it?)